# Allowable topics: people looking to HIRE freelancers having problems?

Tags: discussion, site-topic

After a long weekend, I'm back to the grind stone, and saw [a question](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/non-scamming-job-matching-sites) from the opposite point of view - someone having issues getting good Freelancers.

This user knows not to directly advertise on our sites (yay!), but he does have a problem *in* freelancing, even if he's not the Freelancer himself. I feel we should allow and invite these type of questions, which may help us gain insite to the other side of the conversation. As long as it doesn't turn into a job board, I think it would be allowable.

**What does the community think?**

Comment: Related: http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/239/are-questions-from-employers-clients-on-topic

Answer (score 3):

I say we should tentatively allow this, provided there's no actual advertisement.

Questions about hiring freelancers are fine, but the vast majority (read: all but one) have been advertising, so I'd keep an eye on this.